# GitHub Action is failing when the Personal Access Token is passed as a secret

Tags: github, github-actions

I am using my organisation's Enterprise GitHub account and I have all permissions on the  repo. When creating PAT I have selected all the permissions for PAT (for testing).

GitHub Action is failing when the Personal Access Token is passed as a secret, but the same action is working when I hardcoded the PAT as plain-text in .yml file

The action is working fine with ${{secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN}}

```
- name: Create pull Request
  uses: TheRealWaldo/pull-request@v0.2.0
  env:
   GITHUB_TOKEN: 'Personal-Access-Token-In-Plain-Text'   #{{secrets.PAT}} -> Failing 
  with:
   title: Automated Pull Request From feature-branch Branch
   base: master
   head: feature-branch
   assignee: some-user
   body: Automated Pull Request From feature-branch Branch
```

Comment: How did you set the secret? Using `GITHUB_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.PAT }}` ?

Comment: Yes ${{ secrets.PAT }}

Comment: I've tested [the action here](https://github.com/GuillaumeFalourd/poc-github-actions/blob/main/.github/workflows/workflow-tester27.yml) with this [workflow run](https://github.com/GuillaumeFalourd/poc-github-actions/actions/runs/1964410572) and it seems to work as expected with a secret PAT. It may be related to the secret value you set. But it doesn't seem related to the action.

Comment: Hi GuiFalourd, thanks for taking time looking into this. Just to reiterate the error is when working on my org's GitHub Enterprise account,  the PAT is working fine with a repo that I created under my name, but not with the orgs repo. The action worked fine with my public GitHub account

Comment: Does your personal account have an admin permission scope inside the organization as well? Because if your user isn't an organization admin, that may be why using your PAT works with repos outside the organization, but not for repos inside it.

Comment: A PAT must be authorized against an organization is case your enterprise uses single sign-on: https://docs.github.com/en/enterprise-cloud@latest/authentication/authenticating-with-saml-single-sign-on/authorizing-a-personal-access-token-for-use-with-saml-single-sign-on